# Does every 3-regular bridgeless graph have a perfect matching?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, perfect-matchings

Let $G$ be a simple $3$-regular (every vertex has degree $3$) $2$-edge connected graph. Does $G$ contain a perfect matching?

Comment: Yes.  See Kristal Cantwell's answer below.  My favourite proof of this result is to observe that the vector $(\frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{3}, \dots, \frac{1}{3})$ is in the perfect matching polytope of $G$, and hence $G$ has at least one perfect matching.

Comment: Thanks a lot.
can you please send message, i am new here and i don't know how to make chat

Comment: This is a Q & A site, not a discussion board, and hence chat is not possible.  In the case of the responses you've gotten, both respondents are using their real names and can be googled.  E-mail them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every bridgeless cubic graph contains a perfect matching according to [Petersen's Thereom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petersen%27s_theorem).

Comment: Thanks bro .. how i can make chat with you ?

Answer (score 3):

Just in case you have more questions of this type, there is a theorem of Tutte, which gives necessary/sufficient condition for a graph to have a perfect matching:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tutte_theorem

Since you are forbidding cut edge (bridge), and since an odd component of G-U must send odd number of edges to U (hand shake lemma), each odd component of G-U must sent at least 3 edges to U, but G is cubic, so the condition of the theorem is satisfied.